# DJANGO REST KNOX EXPIRED

Tags: django

I use django rest knox I would not like my session to expire when using my app

````
  'SECURE_HASH_ALGORITHM': 'cryptography.hazmat.primitives.hashes.SHA512',
  'AUTH_TOKEN_CHARACTER_LENGTH': 64,
  'TOKEN_TTL': timedelta(hours=0.0166667),
  'USER_SERIALIZER': 'knox.serializers.UserSerializer',
  'TOKEN_LIMIT_PER_USER': None,
  'AUTO_REFRESH': True,
#   'EXPIRY_DATETIME_FORMAT': api_settings.DATETME_FORMAT
}```
````

Answer (score 0):

The [documentation](https://james1345.github.io/django-rest-knox/settings/) says

> TOKEN_TTL
> This is how long a token can exist before it expires. Expired tokens are automatically removed from the system.

> The setting should be set to an instance of datetime.timedelta. The default is 10 hours ()timedelta(hours=10)).

> **Setting the TOKEN_TTL to None will create tokens that never expire.**

So, to achieve your goal set the **TOKEN_TTL = None**